# Identifying intervals in a time series

Tags: time-series, algorithms, signal-detection

I know, I know, this must have been covered many times before, but my belief is that I don't need the usual robust solution...

Here is a time series:

[image: Time series with intervals]

I would like to automatically detect the intervals which are clearly obvious to the human eye. I highlighted the first one.

The output should be a list of the form [x1, x2], [x3, x4], ...identifying the start and end of each interval on the x axis.

The trick is probably making the tolerance at the edges of each interval a parameter of the solution.

Also how to deal with the 1:15 to 1:23 period, so that it doesn't get identified as an interval, granted it is unlike the other ones.

A trivial approach was to detect when the data crosses the median value, but that is too trivial in less obvious cases.

OK, so, maybe the approach needs to be as robust as necessary, but as simple as possible. ;)

Data for the sample time series:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mqe5afffsx0vr5/series.csv?dl=0

Comment: please post your data .

Comment: I added the data to the initial post.

Comment: I am curious what an "interval" is.  For instance, I see no basis to reject a solution that identifies the apparent inverted peaks--even though that would be quite different from the solution you are suggesting.  Could you provide a more specific description of the patterns you are attempting to identify?

Comment: @whuber Humm, let's see...the data is not random in nature. In this instance, the test called for 6 bursts to be produced. Yet, I would not want the number of intervals to be a parameter. I guess you could say each interval is a period of increased activity preceded and followed by a period of lower activity. Argh, that's a pretty vague description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the details provided in the comments, I assume that the author aims to identify the *bursts* in the time-series, which are described as *intervals*. Detecting when the data crosses the median value would give a uniform solution, since for example in time-series with very high variance (e.g. an EPG) it would result in far too many intervals.

A very simple, **linear**, bursty intervals detection algorithm is described [here](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ruzzo/papers/maxseq.html) by Ruzzo and Tompa, dealing with the problem as a Maximal Scoring Subsequences problem. Granularity can be tuned by re-applying the algorithm on the extracted intervals, until the desired granularity is reached.